# How to assign value to custom class filed

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have,

```
public class demo
{
   public custom[] arr {get;set;}  //custom[] custom type of arr
}

public class custom
{
   public string x {get;set;}
   public string y {get;set;} 
}
```

Now create an object of demo class,

```
demo obj=new demo();

obj.arr[0].x ="nyks";  // no error at compile time.  run time exception.
obj.arr[0].y="str";
```

Is it possible to assign value in `x,y` using an instance of `demo`? 
If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize an array / objects before you can use them

```
demo obj = new demo(); // this is wrong in your code, must be new demo(); 
obj.arr = new custom[1]; // create a new array with 1 customer
obj.arr[0] = new custom(); // fill the array with a new object customer
obj.arr[0].x = "nyks";
obj.arr[0].y = "str";
```

Comment: That was my mistake. sorry it should be new demo();

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.